# Will $y=\sqrt x$ be an into function or onto function?

Tags: functions

Will R $f(x)=\sqrt x$ be an into function or onto function? How to understand from the graph that it will be onto or into function (just by looking at the graph) ?
Domain:positive real numbers
Range:all real numbers

Comment: Please provide definitions, especially for "into function". An onto function is a surjection, but this requires the domain and codomain to be specified. Any function is an onto function onto its range.

Comment: What is the codomain?

Comment: Hint: The way to read surjectivity from a graph: a real function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is onto if every horizontal line intersects the graph of the function somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

No, the square root function is not surjective as a function $\sqrt\cdot:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R$, because the square root of a positive real number is positive real; hence $\sqrt x=-1$ has no solution. It is "into", because the square root always gives real numbers for positive real input.

Generally, a function $f:A\to\Bbb R$ is onto if it touches every horizontal line; in this case it misses any line below the $x$-axis, so it is not onto.

Answer (score 2):

if $y=\sqrt{x} : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$, then it certainly can not be $onto$, since $\sqrt{x} \geq 0$ and then by looking at the graph you will see that negative values are not taken by the function. Also by looking the graph you see that any horizontal line intersects at most one point of the graph, then the function must be 1 to 1.